# Torch7 using weights with unbalanced training sets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, torch, conv-neural-network

I am using a CrossEntropyCriterion with my convnet. I have 150 classes and the number of training files per class is ***very unbalanced*** (5 to 2000 files). According to the documentation, I can compensate for this using weights:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyCriterion([weights])
```

"If provided, the optional argument weights should be a 1D Tensor assigning weight to each of the classes. This is particularly useful when you have an unbalanced training set."

What format should the weights be in? Eg: number training files in class n / total number of training files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to balance your training in this meaning, that small class becomes more important. In general **there are infinitely many possible weightings** leading to various results. One of the simpliest ones, which simply assumes that each class should be equally important (thus efficiently you drop the empirical prior) is to put weight proportional to

```
1 / # samples_in_class
```

for example

```
weight_of_class_y = # all_samples / # samples_in_y
```

This way if you have 5:2000 dissproportion, the smaller class becomes 400 times more important for the model.